# How to get firebase console event details such as first_open, app_remove and Registration_Success using big query for last two weeks?

Tags: sql, firebase, google-bigquery, powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I'm creating visualization for App download count, the app removes count and user registration counts from firebase console data for the last two weeks. It gives us the total count of the selected period but we need date wise count for each. For that, we plan to get the data count using a big query. how do we get all metrics by writing a single query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We will get all the metrics using single query has below

```
SELECT event_date,count(*),platform,event_name FROM `apple-XYZ.analytics_XXXXXX.events_*` where
(event_name = "app_remove" or event_name = "first_open" or event_name = "Registration_Success") and 
(event_date between "20200419" and "20200502") and  (stream_id = "XYZ" or stream_id = "ZYX") and
(platform = "ANDROID" or platform = "IOS") group by platform, event_date, event_name order by event_date;
```

Result: for two weeks (From 19-04-2020 to 02-04-2020)

[image]